# AWS Lambda - resolving 100% CPU issue

Tags: aws-lambda

I started to work with Lambda a few days ago.
Each lambda call is an execution of a CRON job that I have.
I noticed timeouts (5 min) for very simple tasks, that shouldn't consume lots of memory/CPU, and when running them locally, indeed they took less than 20 sec.

Then I've added this code to the main file of the lambda:

```
const libCpuUsage = require('cpu-usage');

libCpuUsage(1000, function (load) {
    if (load > 60)
        console.log("\rCPU LOAD: " + load + "%   ");
});
```

and I see 'CPU LOAD: 100% ' in the logs (sometimes)

and my questions are:

1. how can I find CPU usage of each call
2. I understand that the lambda is running on a docket container (?), and that many events can be sent to the same container. can I limit the # of events?
3. when running on dockers, I gave the tasks 2048 units of CPU, and never got 100% usage. how can I give the same to a lambda
4. any other things I can check?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your questions:

1. To find the parts of your code which are slow when running in AWS Lambda, adding some [logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html) or even better [AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/aws-xray.html) integration with [custom segments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-tracing.html) would help.
2. AWS Lambda is running in containers, but these are no docker containers. Each container works only on one event in parallel, but usually on multiple events sequentially. So if you only have a few events, your AWS Lambda function will probably just run in one container, while it'll run in multiple containers, when you have lots of parallel events (see [Understanding Scaling Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html) for more details).
3. Available CPU-resources in AWS Lambda are directly coupled to the amount of memory you provide to an AWS Lambda function (see [Configuring Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html) for more details). So increasing the amount of memory  Lambda function has available, also increases the available CPU-resources.
4. I suggest you use the suggestions from 1. to figure out what's taking long in your Lambda function and if it's still something which shouldn't take long, ask a separate question for it.

Answer (score 0):

ok so apparently, the issue was io problem rather CPU problem.
the VPC settings of the lambda function were wrong.

also, I'm not sure that the 'cpu-usage' node module can work with lambda containers